# Elm - mapping a list and appending string to the end of each item

Tags: elm

I'm learning Elm and trying to understand how to append a string to all items in a list, but at the end of each entry rather than the beginning.   Sorry for the n00b question but I've read through all the docs/examples around List.map, String (.append, .join) and can't seem to find an answer.

e.g.

```
--create username list
usernames = ["Dave", "Simon", "Sally", "Joe"]    

--create confirmExit function
confirmExit name = String.append " has left the room" name

--apply confirmExit function to all items in username list
List.map (\x -> confirmExit x) usernames
```

Gives me:

```
["has leftDave","has leftSimon","has leftSally","has leftJoe"] : List String
```

But how would I make it so that it returned:

```
["Dave has left","Simon has left","Sally has left","Joe has left"] : List String
```

Is there an equivalent of .append to add to the end instead of the beginning? Please?!

Comment: Suggested improvement: since `\x -> confirmExit x` is the same function as `confirmExit`, use `confirmExit` directly in your `List.map` call: `List.map confirmExit usernames`.

Answer (score 6):

You just have the parameters reversed, try:

```
confirmExit name = String.append name " has left the room"
```

From the [docs](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/String#append):

> append : String -> String -> String
>
> Append two strings. You can also
>   use the (++) operator to do this.
>
> `append "butter" "fly" == "butterfly"`

So you could also use:

```
confirmExit name = name ++ " has left the room"
```

Which is possibly a bit more readable